# Jquery AJAX Progress 'Done x of y'

Tags: jquery, ajax, progress

I have a form that when submitted processes data a set number of times eg: 100. This number is determined by a dropdown list and in the statement 'Done x of **y**' this value is `y`.

The AJAX that is being used is:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST", cache: false,
    data: $('#staff').serializeArray(),
    url: "save.php",    
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data)
    }
});
```

save.php echo's out a value as it completes each turn. This is echoed as 1 or 2 or 3 etc and in the statement 'Done **x** of y' this value is `x`

I'm trying to update a `div` with the latest output from save.php, so I get a live 'Done 1 of 100', 'Done 2 of 100', 'Done 3 of 100' etc message in the div.

I tried adding the following, but that didn't show anything.

```
progress : function(data) {
    console.log(data);
 },
```

Can this be done ?
Thanks

Comment: "progress" is not one of the options available. Read the docs http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/. Here's an example using the raw XHR object: http://stratosprovatopoulos.com/web-development/php/ajax-progress-php-script-without-polling/ . You might also want to consider using something like WebSockets instead.

Comment: Thanks - I've read up one this and have now got it working using: `https://github.com/likerRr/jq-ajax-progress`